# Moved wordpress : broken uploaded files with accents

Tags: php, wordpress

I moved my wordpress website from my old server to my new. Everything works, except that every uploaded files (PDFs for example) with accents (é,à, and so on) in the file name got their URL broken. So I would have to rename every files with accents, and change my links that are pointing to these files.

The images are showing though. It really seems to be only affecting files with accents in the filename.

Any solutions for this? I just wanted to move the wordpress website to my new server. It worked, but I would have to rename all these uploaded files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had such a problem, i dont have 100% correct answer but i want help you.

I remember it was problem with ftp program (i dont remember, maybe winscp?) 
anyway this program does not interact with server and changed accent characters. You can try do it with other program or from server shell.

Second thing, we known which character is wrong and my friend wrote plugin to change characters but if your have you problem from other side (char to accent) this cant work...

Find where is your problem, possible you can fix it with plugin like this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/clean-image-filenames/

Last important thing - check whether your database use correct encoding

Sorry for english ;)